# Get the count of specific column from List of String

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

How do I get the count of a column in a list in `foreach` loop

Model

```
public class Region
{
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public string LanguageName { get; set; }
}
```

View Model

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Region> Regions { get; set; }
}
```

Data

```
 0 LanguageId = 1 LanguageName = "English"
 1 LanguageId = 2 LanguageName = "German"
 2 LanguageId = 3 LanguageName = "French"
 3 LanguageId = 1 LanguageName = "English"
 4 LanguageId = 1 LanguageName = "English"
```

I want the count of `LanguageId` if its greater than 1 than I want to apply some condition

View

```
foreach (var item in Model.Regions)
{   
    if (Model.Regions[item].LanguageId.Count > 1)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

The requirement is to display

```
English (apply condition here because there are more that one)
French
German
```

Comment: What do you mean _count of LanguageId_? `LanguageId` is a property (typeof `int`, not a collection - there is nothing to 'count'). Do you mean you want to test that the value of `LanguageId` is greater than 1? Or do you want to count the number of items in the collection where `LanguageId == 1`?

Comment: I want the count of number of items in the collection where LanguageId == 1.                                                                                                           Have edited my question.

Comment: Still not clear. Do you want the view to be `English - 3`, `German - 1`, `French - 1` - i.e. distinct values with the count of them next to it? (and what is the `Subject : C#` etc you have shown and how does that relate to `Regions`)

Comment: Making it more clear                                                                                           Language : English,French,German.  This is what I want and this is what I am getting                                                                         Language : English,                                                                                               Language : French,                                                                                          Language : German,

Comment: Please see my recent Edit.

Comment: OK, then you just need a `.GroupBy()` clause in your controller (and you will need a view model to include a `Count` property so you can apply the condition in your view. Give me 20 min and I can add an answer if you don't understand

Comment: Please it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need a view model for `Region` that includes the `Name` and `Count` properties

```
public class RegionVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

and then in the controller use a `.GroupBy()` to group the regions by name

```
IEnumerable<Region> regions = .... // your query to get the regions
IEnumerable<RegionVM> model = regions.GroupBy(x => x.LanguageName).Select(x > new RegionVM()
{
    Name = x.Key,
    Count = x.Count()
}.AsEnumerable();
return View(model)
```

and in the view

```
@model IEnumerable<RegionVM>
@foreach(var language in Model)
{
    <div>@language.Name</div>
    if(language.Count > 1)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your time and answer would like to know why are we using View models here as no multiple tables are used.

Comment: What is the logic behind using Name = x.Key,
    Count = x.Count()

Comment: Using a view model has nothing to do with using multiple tables. The purpose of a view model is to represent the data we need in the view, and every view should have a view model specific to it. Refer also [What is ViewModel in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Comment: In your case you need a view model to display the name of the language (`Name` property) and a property for the number of that language (`Count`) so your can preform you conditional view logic.